# endif treated as part of command in autocmd

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, autocmd, multiple-lines, escape

Here is my code:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.c,*.cpp,*.h
  \   let dir=expand('<amatch>:p:h')
  \ | if filereadable(dir.'/Makefile') || filereadable(dir.'/makefile')
  \ |   Make > /dev/null
  \ | endif
```

I want vim to execute the command `Make >> /dev/null` if there is a `Makefile` or `makefile` in the same directory as the current file. However, the command executed is

```
:Dispatch make > /dev/null | endif
```

That is to say, `| endif` is treated as part of the command. How can I tell vim it's part of an if-statement?

The command `Make` and `Dispatch` come from [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch), if it's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `:Make` command you are using is [this one](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch/blob/6dd4480388e4727dfe5c723484c500e03b429c28/plugin/dispatch.vim#L19-L20), then your issue may come from the fact that it was not given the `-bar` attribute when it was defined. See `:h :command-bar`:

```
-bar        The command can be followed by a "|" and another command.
            A "|" inside the command argument is not allowed then.
            Also checks for a " to start a comment.
```

There are other solutions, but the simplest one may be to hide `| endif` from `:Make` by wrapping it inside a string, and executing the latter with `:execute`:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.c,*.cpp,*.h
  \   let dir=expand('<amatch>:p:h')
  \ | if filereadable(dir.'/Makefile') || filereadable(dir.'/makefile')
  \ |   exe 'Make > /dev/null'
  \ | endif
```

For the complete list of commands which, like `:Make`, see the `|` as part of their argument, see `:h :bar`:

```
These commands see the '|' as their argument, and can therefore not be
followed by another Vim command:
    :argdo
    :autocmd
    :bufdo
    :cdo
    :cfdo
    :command
    :cscope
    :debug
    :folddoopen
    :folddoclosed
    :function
    :global
    :help
    :helpfind
    :lcscope
    :ldo
    :lfdo
    :make
    :normal
    :perl
    :perldo
    :promptfind
    :promptrepl
    :pyfile
    :python
    :registers
    :read !
    :scscope
    :sign
    :tcl
    :tcldo
    :tclfile
    :vglobal
    :windo
    :write !
    :[range]!
    a user defined command without the "-bar" argument |:command|
```